# Adding a user's ID to a teacher from a form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following as a table in my HTML for having a student select a teacher

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @teachers.each do |teacher| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= teacher.name %> </td>
        <td><%= teacher.email %> </td>
        <td><%= teacher.phone %> </td>
        <%= form_for teacher do |f| %>
          <td><%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I click the "Select" button (which is yielded from `:button_text`), it doesn't assign the student to the teacher. The controller code for the update action within teachers_controller is

```
def update
  @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
  if params[:user_id]
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if @teacher.users << @user
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'select'
    end
  else
    if @teacher.update_attributes(teacher_params)
      flash[:success] = "Teacher updated"
      redirect_to @teacher
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to make it so that if the hidden_field of the user's ID is present then the only attribute of teacher that is updated is their students, otherwise their attributes (shown in the table) are updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You'll not be passing `params[:user_id]` from your form; it will be `params[:teacher][:user_id]`

```
def update
   @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
   if params[:teacher][:user_id]
     @user = User.find params[:teacher][:user_id]
     if @teacher.users << @user
```

--

You'll be better putting this functionality into a separate method, as to not butcher your `update` action:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :teachers do
    match :users, via: [:patch, :delete] #-> url.com/teachers/:teacher_id/users
end

#app/views/teachers/index.html.erb
<% @teachers.each do |teacher| %>
    <%= button_to "Add", teacher_users_path(teacher), method: :patch, params: { user_id: @user.id } %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/teachers_controller.rb
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
    def users
       @teacher = Teacher.find params[:teacher_id]
       if params[:user_id]
          @user = User.find params[:user_id]
          @teacher.users << @user     if request.patch?
          @teacher.users.delete @user if request.delete?
       end
       redirect_to teachers_path
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm going to need to buy you a case of beer soon. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 0):

ah, you only need one HTML form in your view. you can use a collection select, like so:

```
...
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <%= form_for teacher do |f| %>
         <%= collection_select(:student, :teacher_id, Teacher.all, :id, "#{teacher.name} #{teacher.email} #{teacher.phone}", prompt: true)
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>           
    </td>
  </tr>
       <% end %>
</tbody>
...
```

...then you'll get a `params[:student][:teacher_id]` posted to your controller. You might need to futz with the `collection_select` (or just use a regular `select`) a bit depending on what your models are like. Not totally sure about the hidden field or the if/else in your controller. However, using `form_for` and `collection_select` correctly should get you a long ways. Be sure to RTFM: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select